# Enterprise Architect code generation templates: import hierarchical package structure as a string

Tags: namespaces, code-generation, enterprise-architect

## Problem

In Enterprise Architect 7.1.834 in the code generation templates it is possible to print all the parent packages that a class belongs to in the scope of the File template?

The reason this is needed is to generate multi-include guards compliant with my companies coding standard

---

## What doesn't work

I have tried both:

```
  %list="Namespace__Notes" @separator="-"%
```

and

```
  %packageName%
```

The output of both only prints the top-level parent package (Package1) but I would like to see:

```
  Package1-Package2-Package3
```

Has anyone found a way to do this?

### Namepace__Notes

Namepace__Notes is a custom template with Namepace type, the contents are ar follows

```
  %PI=""%
  %packageName%
```

---

## [Edit] Dirty Solution

My current (dirty) solution is to mangle the file-path.  **Am I missing something?**

The code:

```
$l_backslash = %REPLACE("\z","z","")%
$filepath = %filePath%
$upper_filepath = %TO_UPPER($filepath)%
$upper_package_as_path = $l_backslash + %TO_UPPER(packageName)% + $l_backslash
$upper_package_base_len = %LENGTH(packageName)%

$package_path_pos = %FIND($upper_filepath,$upper_package_as_path)%
%if $package_path_pos != "-1" and $package_path_pos != "0"%
$upper_filepath = %MID($upper_filepath,$package_path_pos)%
%endIf%

$file_define =  "_" + $upper_filepath + "__"
$file_define = %REPLACE($file_define,".","_")%
$file_define = %REPLACE($file_define,$l_backslash,"_")%
$file_define = %REPLACE($file_define,"/","_")% 

$body += "/**************************************************************************//**"
$body += "\n * \file         " + %fileName%
$body += "\n *"
$body += "\n * \brief        " + %elemType% + " " + %className% + " header file"
$body += "\n *"
$body += "\n * \author       " + %classAuthor ? value : "<unknown>"%
$body += "\n *"
$body += "\n *****************************************************************************/"
$body += "\n"
$body += "\n#ifndef " + $file_define
$body += "\n#define " + $file_define
$body += "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

%packagePath% gives you the dot-separated package hierarchy, while %classQualName% yields the ::-separated class hierarchy (for inner classes).

This is for the current version, I don't know whether these macros were present as far back as 7.1. You should seriously consider upgrading, as the current version is 9.3 and EA is backwards-compatible wrt project contents.

Comment: I tried %packagePath% and in my version it only works within the scope of a namespace, but the file-scope I was to referring to is before the namepaces.  In that scope it only prints the <Package1> regardless of package depth.

Also it is never dot-separated (contrary to documentation) but ::-separated, so maybe its a bug.

Answer (score -1):

In EA 10 %packagePath% also gives only top level package in File template

**[Edit] Another dirty and partial solution.**

I'v made a new custom templates, Namespace__fullName:

```
$prevName = %list="Namespace__fullName"%
%if $prevName != ""%
%packageName%::$prevName
%else%
%packageName%
%endIf%
```

;
and Class__fullQualName:

```
%list="Namespace__fullName"%::%classQualName%
```

This will work in simple cases when the source file contains only 1 class (possibly with nested items) and, therefore, only 1 namespaces hierarchy.